# No backend listener in jmeter 2.11

Tags: jmeter, junit4, influxdb, grafana

How do i use backend listener in JMETER 2.11. I am trying to run Junit4 Test Cases on jmeter 2.11 and need to add it in my Influxdb and Grafana. How can i use backend listener in 2.11

[Image that shows the selection of the junit testcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrxDv.png)

[Image that shows that the test selected is rechecked by some default groovy test case/Selenese Test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdqJD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.
Upgrade to 2.13 and it will be available.

Why do you want to stay in 2.11 ?

Comment: in 2.13 when i am selecting any junit 4 test using junit request sampler it gets unchecked as soon as click anything else and this does not happen in Jmeter 2.11. HAVE ADDED THE SCREENSHOTS IN THE QUESTION. It would be great if you could help. Thanx

Comment: hi, ask another question on this and I will answer, this will help other users. Accept this one